# Angular Ag-Grid not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to use Angular [Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) in my Web Application.

I've followed these tutorials

1. [Angular Grid | Get Started with ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/)
2. [ag-Grid Angular Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-angular)

**Problem / Issue**
I Follwed every thing exactly. Even data is being loaded in grid but View is not very appreciable. Here what I'm getting  (not alignment, no coloring) 
[image]

**What I tried** I search extensively over Google and Stack Overflow. Some Answers recommend that `CSS` is not loading Properly ( which is solid argument) but I double check my import statements on `Component.css` and Also tried adding `.css` reference in `index.html`. The `.css` files which I refer are exists and reference was also good.

**What I Expect**

[image]

**Codes**

***appComponent.html***

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

***appComponent.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Grid } from 'ag-grid/main';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'Grid1';
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
    { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
    { headerName: "Price", field: "price" },
  ];

  rowData = [
    { make: "Toyota", model: "m1", price: 35351 },
    { make: "Ford", model: "m2", price: 6546 },
    { make: "M3", model: "m3", price: 646 },
    { make: "M765", model: "m4", price: 56486 }
  ]
}
```

***app.component.scss***

```
@import "~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

I Also tried other tutorial which says this `app.component.scss`

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ag Grid styles should be imported in styles.scss not in app.component.scss

So try to import in styles.scss and check:

```
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

Comment: How come this is not documented? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Makky ag-grid documentation is not as good as angular

Comment: You can use the minified editions too: `ag-grid.min.css` and `ag-theme-batham.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered quite a different but similar situation in that after configuring and integrating agGrid, the features work as expected but the display doesn't render really well. For instance, the sorting and filter icon doesn't render, checkbox not displaying when enabled.

I realized it was because I selected a different theme in the HTML from the one imported in the global style.css/scss.

Answer (score 0):

first you must be add related modules in `app.module.ts`
after that you can add directly CSS sources in your html file
like this:

### app.component.html

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"
  />
</head>

<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post it here since this is the first result in Google search.

Had the same issue:
React + Storybook are not displaying correctly `ag-grid` with dark/light custom themes.

Putting default `@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid";` into common `style.css` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing in `react-ag-grid`, solved by importing the styles.

```
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

At the root of your project folder, import the grid styles into your `styles.scss` file, like this:

```
@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '~ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
```

or with relative path

```
@import '../node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import '../node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
```

or with CDN

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@28.2.0/styles/ag-grid.css');
@import url('https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@28.2.0/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css');
```

When integrated, don't forget to re-run the server, `npm run ng serve`, the table grid should render correctly with style as expected.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the main problem is, the CDN files contains more styles than the ag-grid installed by npm , my solution was used the CND from index.html in my angular 12 project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).